# free object isomorphisms

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

In group category if $F_1$ be a free object on $X_1$ and $F_2$ is free object on $X_2$ and $F_1$ isomorphic to $F_2$ prove that |$X_1$|=|$X_2$|

whats the relationship between isomorphisms of free objects and cardinality of $X_i$ ?

Comment: Hint: consider the abelianisations of $F_1$ and $F_2$ and use the fact that free abelian groups have a well-defined rank.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the abelization $G^{ab}=G/{[G,G]}$, where $[G,G]$ is the commutator-subgroup of $G$.

If $F_1\cong F_2$, we get $$\mathbb{Z}^{|X_1|}\cong F_1^{ab}\cong F_2^{ab}\cong \mathbb{Z}^{|X_2|}.$$
Tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$, one gets $$\mathbb{Q}^{|X_1|}\cong \mathbb{Z}^{|X_1|}\otimes\mathbb{Q}\cong\mathbb{Z}^{|X_2|}\otimes\mathbb{Q}\cong\mathbb{Q}^{|X_2|}.$$
This means we have an isomorphism $\mathbb{Q}^{|X_1|}\cong\mathbb{Q}^{|X_2|}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$-vectorspaces and since the dimension of vectorspaces is well-defined even in infinity dimensions ([dimension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces)) we get $|X_1|=|X_2|$.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative proof is to observe that the cardinality of the underlying set of $F(X)$ equals the cardinality of $X$.